# A word to say you have deep passion for an idea

Tags: word-choice

What is the best word for saying that I have a deep passion about an idea, saying that I agree with it and connect to it?

For instance:

> I am very ___ with Eran's Idea.

Comment: Maybe you're "into" Eran's idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*enthused* is an option here. *into* would also be a choice but it can't be used with *with*.

> I am very into Eran's idea.

is okay though.

Answer (score 2):

The best word to fit into that sentence exactly as written would be:

> I am very **taken** with Eran's idea.